# getting average values from a join

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have this query in BigQuery. But I want the query to return the average engagement rate BY category. I'm very new to SQL, so not too sure how to do this. I tried adding in SELECT AVG(engagement_rate) but got error messsages.

```
SELECT engagement_rate,category_id, name
FROM `public_instagram_channels` AS engrate
JOIN `public_influencer_categories`AS categorydata
ON engrate.engagement_rate=categorydata.influencer_id 
JOIN `public_categories`AS categoryname
ON categoryname.id=categorydata.category_id
```

| engagement_rate | category_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.5 | 2. | Beauty |
| 2 | 1. | Home |
| 2.5 | 3. | Fashion |
| 3.2 | 2. | Beauty |
| 2.6 | 2. | Beauty |

NEEDED OUTPUT:

| engagement_rate | category_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2.4 | 2. | Beauty |
| 2 | 1. | Home |
| 2.5 | 3. | Fashion |

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`!

Answer (score 0):

You want an aggregation query:

```
SELECT AVG(pic.engagement_rate), c.id as category_id, c.name
FROM `public_instagram_channels` pic
     `public_influencer_categories` pinfc
     ON pic.engagement_rate = pinfc.influencer_id JOIN
     `public_categories`AS c
     ON c.id = pinfc.category_id 
GROUP BY 2, 3;
```

Note:  I changed the table aliases to be abbreviations for the table names.  I find those easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Basic concept behind is getting `GROUP BY` and then calculating `AVERAGE`.
Sample Query is given below, where `Group By` is done on coll category_id & name, then we calculated `AVERAGE`

```
WITH data AS (
SELECT
1.5 as engagement_rate1, 2 as category_id,  'Beauty' as name union all select 
2,  1,  'Home' union all select 
2.5,    3,  'Fashion' union all select 
3.2,    2,  'Beauty' union all select 
2.6,    2,  'Beauty'
) 
--select * from data
SELECT distinct avg(engagement_rate1)  , category_id,  name  from data
group by category_id, name
```

Answer (score 0):

Just missing a GROUP BY

```
SELECT category_id, name, avg(engagement_rate)
FROM `public_instagram_channels` AS engrate
JOIN `public_influencer_categories`AS categorydata
ON engrate.engagement_rate=categorydata.influencer_id 
JOIN `public_categories`AS categoryname
ON categoryname.id=categorydata.category_id 
group by category_id, name
```

I'd recommend using the table alias to identify what column is coming from what table.
Same applies for the GROUP BY

ie. `SELECT categoryname.category_id, categoryname.name, avg(categorydata.engagement_rate)`